# mnist dataset Lenet training

Tags: caffe, mnist

I am new to caffe. To train Lenet with mnist dataset,I downloaded the data to the data/mnist in caffe. 
When trying to convert to lmdb, using `./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh` ,  I get error as :

```
 Creating lmdb...
F0225 16:39:23.937786 23330 convert_mnist_data.cpp:45] Check failed: image_file Unable to open file data/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f5d0f0e8daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f5d0f0e8ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f5d0f0e86e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f5d0f0eb687  (unknown)
    @           0x4045df  convert_dataset()
    @           0x402943  main
    @     0x7f5d0de99ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x40298c  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
F0225 16:39:24.025714 23334 convert_mnist_data.cpp:45] Check failed: image_file Unable to open file data/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7faa1af57daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7faa1af57ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7faa1af576e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7faa1af5a687  (unknown)
    @           0x4045df  convert_dataset()
    @           0x402943  main
    @     0x7faa19d08ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x40298c  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
Done.
```

Can somebody help me with this? What exactly could be the issue?

Comment: The downloaded data might be corrupted, try downloading them again.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Tried that, doesn't help.

Comment: Are those files downloaded. Check if its present in data/mnist/. What is the size of both files

Comment: Yes, it was there in the needed folder of the appropriate size.

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual compilation worked, though the script failed for unknown reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use absolutely path not like `data/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte`.caffe sometimes can't get it.

Answer (score 2):

rename your mnist dataset,because you downloaded mnist dataset maybe was "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte" but it is the "t10k-images-idx3-ubyte" in create_mnist.sh,so you have to use '-'instead of '.'

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. In **$CAFFE_ROOT/data/minist/get_mnist.sh**, line 15: **gunzip ${fname}.gz** I use ubuntu 14.04 and I don't know why it failed when gunzip train-images-idx3-ubyte.tz and t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.tz.

As a result, there are no train-images-idx3-ubyte and t10k-images-idx3-ubyte. In $CAFFE_ROOT/examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh,  it failed to convert them to lmdb format.

So I just gunzip them in OSX and then conversion worked.

Answer (score 0):

Download the mnist dataset from another location (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), place them in $CAFFE_ROOT/data/ and unzip them. After that ./examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh works when run from $CAFFE_ROOT. At least for me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your script from the $CAFFE_ROOT, such as the following:

```
sudo sh /examples/mnist/create_mnist.sh
```